# Capture msbuild tf.exe changeset /latest

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, changeset

Within an MSBuild file I would like to extract the `changeset` number from the output of the following command into a `$(parameter)` value;

```
<Exec Command="c:\path\tf.exe changeset /latest /i" />
```

In my build script I can see the Changeset number in the first line of the result:

> Changeset: 7539
>   User: John Doe 
>   Date: 23 September 2015 17:03:19
>
> Comment:
>     some check-in comment
>
> Items:
>   [[List of items here]]
>
> Work Items:
>   [[List of linked work items here]]

I feel like I am very close and want the simplest solution. I can use MSBuild.ExtensionPack or the MSBuild.Community tasks if there is a better option.

Comment: second link : https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22changeset+%2Flatest+%2Fi%22+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @granadaCoder these links don't show how to _extract_ the changeset value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To only get the changeset number, please try the following steps: (code is quoted from this [link](https://gist.github.com/JamesWoolfenden/7470026)):

1. Download and install [MSBuildExtensionPack](https://github.com/mikefourie/MSBuildExtensionPack/releases) on the machine
2. Add the following code to the .csproj file (assume you're working with a C# project). Note that: you need to change the folder path where **MSBuild.ExtensionPack.TaskFactory.PowerShell.dll** is installed on your machine for the **AssemblyFile** property.

```html
  <UsingTask TaskFactory="PowershellTaskFactory" TaskName="Changeset" AssemblyFile="C:\Program Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.TaskFactory.PowerShell.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <changeset Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <![CDATA[  
       $tf = & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" history . /r /noprompt /stopafter:1 /version:W 
       $changeset=$tf[2].Split(" ")[0] 
       ]]>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
  <Target Name="TestBuild">
    <Changeset>
      <Output TaskParameter="changeset" PropertyName="changeset" />
    </Changeset>
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Changeset:++++++ ::::: $(changeset)" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some new standard MsBuild features to achieve this.

```
<PropertyGroup> 
  <TF>&quot;$(VS140COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\tf.exe&quot;</TF> 
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="GetVersion">
  <Exec Command="$(TF) changeset /latest /i" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
    <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="TfOutput" />
  </Exec>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Changeset>$(TfOutput.Split(';')[0].Substring(11))</Changeset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Message Importance="high" Text="ChangeSet is $(Changeset)" />
</Target>
```